# Mysql query count certain values

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, case

Trying to create a mysql query where it count the names of the filters database. Successful, getting names from a certain period is  the main goal.

```
$query = query("
SELECT count(CASE WHEN filter='冬越しする(現在地検索)' THEN 1 END) as filter, 
count(CASE WHEN filter='開花期で選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter2, 
count(CASE WHEN filter='日当たりで選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter3,  
count(CASE WHEN filter='株幅で選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter4,
count(CASE WHEN filter='背丈で選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter5, 
count(CASE WHEN filter='機能、タイプで選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter6,
count(CASE WHEN filter='ビギナーおすすめ' THEN 1 END) as filter7 FROM 
filter_clicked WHERE filter_date < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've to user now()-now()-interval 30 day - what you've used it is sql server function

```
$query = query("
SELECT count(CASE WHEN filter='冬越しする(現在地検索)' THEN 1 END) as filter, 
count(CASE WHEN filter='開花期で選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter2, 
count(CASE WHEN filter='日当たりで選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter3,  
count(CASE WHEN filter='株幅で選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter4,
count(CASE WHEN filter='背丈で選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter5, 
count(CASE WHEN filter='機能、タイプで選ぶ' THEN 1 END) as filter6,
count(CASE WHEN filter='ビギナーおすすめ' THEN 1 END) as filter7 FROM 
filter_clicked WHERE filter_date < date(now())-interval 30 day")
```

Comment: Wow man, never heard of the now() function, works . perfectly! Thank . you

Comment: I . can push answer . in 7 minutes :)

Comment: I can in 5 minutes it . says, you were to fast . haha :)

Comment: `NOW()` return `DATETIME` format e.g: `2019-03-04 16:13:12`. Whereas `CURRENT_DATE` or `CURDATE()` return `DATE` only e.g: `2019-03-04`.

Comment: @tcadidot0, yes you are right here too anyway, I've converted now() to date